# Is it possible to edit template name at compile time?

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to modify template type given at compile time but unable to do it. Let see if you have some idea.

Lets consider we have 2 classes class A and A_test and one template class B. 
Will implemented class B as it is having a function b_f() which is internaly creating an object of template class and calling public funcion A_f()/A_test_f() of class A or Class A_test.

from main, will be creating class B obj; obj.b_f(); 
but I want to creat an object of class A_test not class A.

Let me know if it is possible.

Basicaly I wanted to do object injection. Please let me know if it is possible.

Comment: Code please?? Post some code as well to show us what exactly and how exactly you're doing!

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to do? Because I really have no idea what you're trying to deal with.

Comment: if you want to control types that b_f operates on, you need to pass it the type...

Answer (score 1):

The best solution by far is to try to rename A_test_f() to be the same as A_f().

If that proves impossible, the next thing I'd try is to specialize class B:

```
template<class AT>
class B {
public: b_f() {
    AT m_A;
    m_A.A_f();
};

template<>
class B<A_test> {
public: b_f() {
    AT m_A;
    m_A.A_test_f();
};
```

If `B` is too complicated, there are other things to try, but you probably want to rethink what you're doing first.  If all else fails, do what I coded above here, but call it `B_HELPER` instead of `B` and then b_f() can do: `B_HELPER<AT> m_A;  m_A.b_f();`  That way you don't have to recode all of `B`.

Answer (score 0):

The common way to inject dependencies into templates at compile-time is through type traits.  This allows customizing the templates externally through another struct or class which has specific knowledge of the class.  Examples in the standard library include [`std::char_traits<>`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/char_traits.html) and [`std::iterator_traits<>`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/iterator_traits.html).  Boost also defines some, including [`boost::type_traits<>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/libs/type_traits/cxx_type_traits.htm).

Traits involve defining a struct for the general case and specializing it for alternate cases when necessary.

```
  // general case: select method named "f".
template<class T> struct b_traits
{
    typedef void(T*F)();
    static const F f = &T::f;
};

  // template type that forwards method selection to "b_traits" struct.
template<class AT>
class B {
public: b_f() {
    AT m_A;
    (m_A.*(b_traits<AT>::f))();
};

class A_test { ... };

  // special case: select method named "A_test_f".
template<> struct b_traits<A_test>
{
    typedef void(T*F)();
    static const F f = &A_test::A_test_f;
};

int main ()
{
    B<A_test> b;
    b.b_f(); // will invoke "A_test::A_test_f()" rather than "A_test::f()".
}
```